# Ruby: check if directory exists

Tags: ruby

How can I check if a directory exists in Ruby?
I tried with this but it didn't want to work.

```
rescue Errno::ENOENT
puts "Directory does not exist"
```

Comment: Please can you post full code , I can guess you missed the right part of the code

Answer (score 5):

```
if Dir.exist?('/home/foo/bar/baz')
  ... 
else
  ... 
end
```

Comment: its working now but the - rescue TypeError puts "Give me a directory" - become wrong

Comment: @mat3: sorry, I don't understand.